# Angular 2 - Interpolation for NGX-Charts Results within ngFor

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I'm trying to show charts based on some json. I made a pipe to access the various parts of the json object but don't know how to use the data, which  looks like this:

```
[ { "name": "Completed", "value": 50 }, { "name": "Remaining", "value": 50 } ]
```

within the ngFor.

So normally I would do something like this:

```
  <ngx-charts-advanced-pie-chart
    mdTooltip="Click to change unit"
    [tooltipDisabled] = "true"
    [scheme]="colorScheme"
    [results]="results"     <----this is where the results normally go
    [gradient]="gradient"
    [view]="view"
    (select)="onChartClick()"
    >
  </ngx-charts-advanced-pie-chart>
```

And I want to try something like this:

```
 <div *ngFor="let chair of targetChairs | chairDimensions">
  <ngx-charts-advanced-pie-chart
    mdTooltip="Click to change unit"
    [tooltipDisabled] = "true"
    [scheme]="colorScheme"
    [results]="{{ chair.value.data.height | json }}"
    [gradient]="gradient"
    [view]="view"
    (select)="onChartClick()"
    >
  </ngx-charts-advanced-pie-chart>
</div>
```

This doesn't work but is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a similar issue on a git page [here](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/52) which solved my problem, so here is what I used in case someone else has this problem:

```
 <div *ngFor="let chair of targetChairs | chairDimensions">
  <ngx-charts-advanced-pie-chart
    mdTooltip="Click to change unit"
    [tooltipDisabled] = "true"
    [scheme]="colorScheme"
    [results]="chair.value.data.feet"
    [gradient]="gradient"
    [view]="view"
    (select)="onChartClick()"
    >
  </ngx-charts-advanced-pie-chart>
</div>
```